# convery my own datasets to Cifar10 format (X_train, y_train),(X_test, y_test)

Tags: python

I have a data set composed of two folders each folder contains images, and I want convert my data set into Cifar10 datasets to use it on code which i found it in Github , 
like this :

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test), label_names = load_cifar10
```

please  help !!

Comment: please add you attempt for solving the problem (working code example).

Answer (score 0):

class ImageLoader:
    """Load images in arrays without batches."""

```
def __init__(self, train_dir, test_dir):
    """Create class."""
    self.train_dir = train_dir
    self.test_dir = test_dir

def load_data(self):
    """Load the data."""
    features, labels = [], []

    for source in [self.train_dir, self.test_dir]:
        input, output = [], []
        for class_name in os.listdir(source):
            if os.path.isdir(class_name):
                for img_name in os.listdir(class_name):
                    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(self.train_dir, class_name, img_name))

                    # ...
                    # Modify your image array here.
                    # ...

                    input.append(img)
                    output.append(class_name)  # or other method to convert label

        # Shuffle labels.
        combine = list(zip(input, output))  # zip as list for Python 3
        np.random.shuffle(combine)
        input, output = zip(*combine)
        features.append(input)
        labels.append(output)

    return [[np.array(features[0], dtype=np.float32),
             np.array(labels[0], dtype=np.float32)],
            [np.array(features[1], dtype=np.float32),
             np.array(labels[1], dtype=np.float32)]]
```

cifar10 = ImageLoader('path-to-training', 'path-to-testing')
(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = cifar10.load_data()